# Qt ActiveX WMI QAxBase::dynamicCallHelper: ItemIndex(int): No such property in

Tags: qt, activex, wmi, activeqt

I am very new to Windows Programming. Here Goes My code

```
objIWbemLocator = new QAxObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
objWMIService = objIWbemLocator->querySubObject("ConnectServer(QString&,QString&)",QString("."),QString("root\\cimv2"));

QAxObject* returnList = objWMIService->querySubObject("ExecQuery(QString&)", QString("select * from %1").arg(domain));
QAxObject* result = returnList->querySubObject("ItemIndex(int)", 0);
```

I am getting the Error on Runtime

```
Qt ActiveX WMI QAxBase::dynamicCallHelper: ItemIndex(int): No such property in
```

But [`ItemIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826600%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
 Method Exists

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826600%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) says that

> The ItemIndex method does not work
>   with collections which do not contain
>   SWbemObjects, such as SWbemMethodSet,
>   SWbemNamedValueSet, SWbemPrivilegeSet,
>   SWbemPropertySet, and
>   SWbemQualifierSet.

What are you selecting ? Have you tried iterating over the collection ? Plus you need minimum Windows Vista for ItemIndex method. I hope this helps

Comment: Well How to iterate over the collection ? Can you show Me some example ? I saw no *Iterator Class on that Documentation can you point me to some example ?

Comment: See this link http://www.qtforum.org/article/31970/how-do-i-get-use-the-ienumerable-interface-in-qt.html. If you get it working please post your code too so that we all can benefit from your experience. Thanks